# How to create my own style for latex presentation?

Tags: latex, presentation

The number of templates for latex presentation is quite limited. How could one create a style/class file for latex presentation using e.g. ones university's symbolic, colors and pictures.
Google only shows the links about how to create presentation itself.

Answer (score 0):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106662/how-to-make-my-own-latex-template

visit https://tex.stackexchange.com/ your question is more relevant on that site